# Mac OSX: How to pass a file descriptor from user space to a driver?

Tags: macos, kernel-module, file-descriptor

This is my requirement: I need to transfer a big binary file (~400MB) from a user application to a kernel module as input for some kind of "hardware calculation". The thing is, I need to transfer the big file.

I was looking for the best way to do it and I found that it is possible to share a file descriptor pointing to the binary data from user space and make it available directly from the kernel module. I have been reading a lot of theory about ioctl, IPC, etc but I am not sure about what should be the best approach to solve this requirement. I really appreciate any piece of code I could start from... any hint?

Comment: I'm not a kernel guy, but I would have thought sharing memory from user space to kernel space would be better (i.e. the user process sets-up the shared memory and passes it to the kernel): https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1197/_index.html

Comment: A very detailed and handy post about how to share data between user applications and kernel drivers for OSX can be found right here -> http://wagerlabs.com/blog/2008/02/04/writing-a-mac-osx-usb-device-driver-that-implements-scsi-pass-through/ including source code to study -> https://github.com/wagerlabs/seaforth24